# Java Android Sudoku solver

Tags: java, algorithm, android, sudoku

I made a simple and non recursive Android Java Sudoku solver implementing Algorithm X with links inspired from dancing links.  The code is [on Github](https://github.com/pc1211/SUDOKU_A/tree/3db4ac8450b76d3271c71becd6e2e85cef3b984a) (start with the Solver class and the SatsNodesHandler class).

The "dancing links" implementation seemed to me too tricky as it implies a lot of unlink and relink operations between nodes to cover or uncover the same rows and columns in the way.

That's why I implemented links, but with these properties:

- Only right and down links in the nodes (connecting the "1" in the 729x324 matrix)
- Row and column headers featuring a “cover ID” equal to the depth level reached when covered (0 if uncovered)
- A stack of candidate nodes fed by the non recursive solver algorithm

**Here is the Solver class:**

```
package com.example.pgyl.sudoku_a;

public class Solver {
    public interface onSolveEndListener {
        void onSolveEnd();
    }

    public void setOnSolveEndListener(onSolveEndListener listener) {
        mOnSolveEndListener = listener;
    }

    private onSolveEndListener mOnSolveEndListener;

    //region Constantes
    public enum SOLVE_STATES {
        UNKNOWN, SOLUTION_FOUND, IMPOSSIBLE
    }
    //endregion

    //region Variables
    private SatsNodesHandler satsNodesHandler;
    private SOLVE_STATES solveState;
    private SatsNode candidate;
    //endregion

    public Solver(SatsNodesHandler satsNodesHandler) {
        this.satsNodesHandler = satsNodesHandler;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        solveState = SOLVE_STATES.UNKNOWN;
    }

    public void close() {
        satsNodesHandler = null;
    }

    public void reset() {
        satsNodesHandler.reset();
        candidate = null;
        resetSolveState();
    }

    public void resetSolveState() {
        solveState = SOLVE_STATES.UNKNOWN;
    }

    public SOLVE_STATES getSolveState() {
        return solveState;
    }

    public void solve() {
        if (solveState.equals(SOLVE_STATES.IMPOSSIBLE)) {
            reset();
        } else {
            if (solveState.equals(SOLVE_STATES.SOLUTION_FOUND)) {   //  Pour continuer
                satsNodesHandler.discardLastSolution();
                satsNodesHandler.uncoverRowsAndCols();
                candidate = satsNodesHandler.getNextCandidate();
                if (candidate != null) {
                    solveState = SOLVE_STATES.UNKNOWN;
                } else {
                    solveState = SOLVE_STATES.IMPOSSIBLE;
                }
            }
            while (solveState.equals(SOLVE_STATES.UNKNOWN)) {
                SatsNode colHeader = satsNodesHandler.chooseColumn();
                if (colHeader != null) {
                    if (colHeader.rowCount > 0) {
                        if (candidate != null) {
                            satsNodesHandler.appendSolution(candidate);
                        }
                        satsNodesHandler.setNextCandidates(colHeader);
                    } else {
                        satsNodesHandler.uncoverRowsAndCols();
                    }
                    candidate = satsNodesHandler.getNextCandidate();
                    if (candidate == null) {
                        solveState = SOLVE_STATES.IMPOSSIBLE;
                    }
                } else {
                    satsNodesHandler.appendSolution(candidate);
                    satsNodesHandler.solutionsToCells();
                    solveState = SOLVE_STATES.SOLUTION_FOUND;
                }
            }
        }
        if (mOnSolveEndListener != null) {
            mOnSolveEndListener.onSolveEnd();
        }
    }

}
```

**Here is the SatsNodesHandler class:**

```
package com.example.pgyl.sudoku_a;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SatsNodesHandler {

    //region Variables
    private ArrayList<SatsNode> nodes;
    private ArrayList<SatsNode> candidateStack;
    private ArrayList<Integer> solutionStack;
    private SatsNode rootHeader;
    private CellsHandler cellsHandler;
    private boolean[][] sats;
    private Cell[] cells;
    private int gridSize;
    private int gridRows;
    private int squareRows;
    private int level;
    //endregion

    public SatsNodesHandler(CellsHandler cellsHandler) {
        this.cellsHandler = cellsHandler;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        cells = cellsHandler.getCells();
        gridSize = cellsHandler.getGridSize();
        gridRows = cellsHandler.getGridRows();
        squareRows = cellsHandler.getSquareRows();
        candidateStack = new ArrayList<SatsNode>();
        solutionStack = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        nodes = new ArrayList<SatsNode>();
    }

    public void close() {
        candidateStack.clear();
        candidateStack = null;
        solutionStack.clear();
        solutionStack = null;
        nodes.clear();
        nodes = null;
        cells = null;
    }

    public void reset() {
        cellsHandler.deleteAllUnprotectedCells();
        nodes.clear();
        candidateStack.clear();
        solutionStack.clear();
        createSatsMatrix();
        mergeCellsIntoSatsMatrix();
        satsMatrixToSatsNodes();
        level = 0;
    }

    public void setNextCandidates(SatsNode colHeader) {
        level = level + 1;
        SatsNode nc = colHeader.down;
        while (!nc.equals(colHeader)) {
            if (nc.rowHeader.coverId == 0) {  //  Ligne non couverte
                nc.level = level;             //  On inscrit le niveau actuel dans le noeud simple
                pushCandidate(nc);
            }
            nc = nc.down;
        }
    }

    public SatsNode getNextCandidate() {
        SatsNode ret = popCandidate();
        if (ret != null) {
            if (ret.level < level) {      //  Le noeud simple date d'un niveau antérieur
                level = ret.level;
                discardLastSolution();    //  Enlever la dernière solution car on doit revenir à un niveau antérieur
                uncoverRowsAndCols();     //  Restaurer parfois plusieurs niveaux en une fois si (level - ret.level) > 1
            }
            coverRowsAndCols(ret);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public SatsNode chooseColumn() {
        SatsNode ret = null;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        SatsNode ch = rootHeader.right;
        while (!ch.equals(rootHeader)) {
            if (ch.coverId == 0) {      //  Colonne non couverte
                int rc = rowCount(ch);
                if (rc < min) {         //  Chercher la colonne avec le minimum de 1 (parmi ses lignes non couvertes)
                    min = rc;
                    ret = ch;
                    if (min == 0) {     //  Plus bas impossible
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            ch = ch.right;
        }
        if (ret != null) {
            ret.rowCount = min;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public void appendSolution(SatsNode satsNode) {
        solutionStack.add(satsNode.rowHeader.satsRow);
    }

    public void discardLastSolution() {
        int size = solutionStack.size();
        if (size > 0) {
            solutionStack.remove(size - 1);
        }
    }

    public void solutionsToCells() {
        int size = solutionStack.size();
        if (size > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= (size - 1); i = i + 1) {
                int satsRow = solutionStack.get(i);
                int row = (satsRow / gridSize);
                int col = (satsRow % gridSize) / gridRows;
                int cellIndex = gridRows * row + col;
                cells[cellIndex].value = (satsRow % gridRows) + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public void uncoverRowsAndCols() {     //  Découvrir les lignes et colonnes nécessaires pour revenir à un niveau antérieur
        SatsNode rh = rootHeader.down;
        while (!rh.equals(rootHeader)) {
            if (rh.coverId >= level) {
                rh.coverId = 0;            //  Découvrir la ligne
            }
            rh = rh.down;
        }
        SatsNode ch = rootHeader.right;
        while (!ch.equals(rootHeader)) {
            if (ch.coverId >= level) {
                ch.coverId = 0;           //  Découvrir la colonne
            }
            ch = ch.right;
        }
    }

    private void coverRowsAndCols(SatsNode satsNode) {  //  Couvrir les lignes et colonnes liées au noeud
        SatsNode rh = satsNode.rowHeader;
        SatsNode nr = rh.right;
        while (!nr.equals(rh)) {
            SatsNode ch = nr.colHeader;
            if (ch.coverId == 0) {      //  Colonne non couverte
                ch.coverId = level;     //  Couvrir la colonne (en utilisant le niveau actuel comme Id)
                SatsNode nc = ch.down;
                while (!nc.equals(ch)) {
                    SatsNode rhc = nc.rowHeader;
                    if (rhc.coverId == 0) {    //  Ligne non couverte
                        rhc.coverId = level;   //  Couvrir la ligne (en utilisant le niveau actuel comme Id)
                    }
                    nc = nc.down;
                }
            }
            nr = nr.right;
        }
    }

    private int rowCount(SatsNode colHeader) {  // Compter le nombre de 1 d'une colonne (parmi ses lignes non couvertes)
        int ret = 0;
        SatsNode nc = colHeader.down;
        while (!nc.equals(colHeader)) {
            if (nc.rowHeader.coverId == 0) {   //  Ligne non couverte
                ret = ret + 1;
            }
            nc = nc.down;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private void pushCandidate(SatsNode SatsNode) {
        candidateStack.add(SatsNode);
    }

    private SatsNode popCandidate() {
        SatsNode ret = null;
        int size = candidateStack.size();
        if (size > 0) {
            ret = candidateStack.get(size - 1);
            candidateStack.remove(size - 1);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private void satsMatrixToSatsNodes() {
        int candidates = sats.length;
        int constraints = sats[0].length;

        SatsNode[] colHeaders = new SatsNode[constraints];
        SatsNode[] lastRowNodes = new SatsNode[constraints];
        SatsNode lastColNode = new SatsNode();

        rootHeader = new SatsNode();
        nodes.add(rootHeader);
        rootHeader.right = rootHeader;    //  Pas encore d'entêtes de colonne => L'entête des entêtes pointe vers elle-même
        rootHeader.down = rootHeader;     //  Pas encore d'entêtes de ligne => L'entête des entêtes pointe vers elle-même
        SatsNode lastRowHeader = rootHeader;
        SatsNode lastColHeader = rootHeader;

        for (int i = 0; i <= (candidates - 1); i = i + 1) {
            SatsNode rowHeader = null;
            for (int j = 0; j <= (constraints - 1); j = j + 1) {
                if (sats[i][j]) {
                    SatsNode node = new SatsNode();
                    nodes.add(node);                  //  Création noeud simple
                    if (rowHeader == null) {
                        rowHeader = new SatsNode();   //  Le noeud simple est le 1er de sa ligne => Création Entête de ligne
                        nodes.add(rowHeader);
                        rowHeader.right = node;       //  L'entête de ligne pointe vers le 1er noeud simple de sa ligne
                        rowHeader.satsRow = i;
                        if (rootHeader.down.equals(rootHeader)) {
                            rootHeader.down = rowHeader;   //  L'entête des entêtes pointe vers la 1e entête de ligne
                        }
                    } else {
                        lastColNode.right = node;     //  Le noeud simple précédent (de la même ligne) pointe vers celui-ci
                    }
                    if (colHeaders[j] == null) {
                        colHeaders[j] = new SatsNode();    //  Le noeud simple est le 1er de sa colonne => Création Entête de colonne
                        nodes.add(colHeaders[j]);
                        colHeaders[j].down = node;         //  L'entête de colonne pointe vers le 1er noeud simple de sa colonne
                        if (rootHeader.right.equals(rootHeader)) {
                            rootHeader.right = colHeaders[j];   //  L'entête des entêtes pointe vers la 1e entête de colonne
                        }
                        lastRowNodes[j] = new SatsNode();
                    } else {
                        lastRowNodes[j].down = node;       //  Le noeud simple précédent (de la même colonne) pointe vers celui-ci
                    }
                    node.rowHeader = rowHeader;
                    node.colHeader = colHeaders[j];
                    lastColNode = node;                //  Le dernier noeud simple (de la même ligne) est celui-ci
                    lastRowNodes[j] = node;            //  Le dernier noeud simple (de la même colonne) est celui-ci
                }
            }
            if (rowHeader != null) {
                lastColNode.right = rowHeader;         //  Le dernier noeud simple de la ligne pointe vers l'entête de ligne
                lastRowHeader.down = rowHeader;        //  La précédente entête de ligne pointe vers celle-ci
                lastRowHeader = rowHeader;             //  La dernière entête de ligne est celle-ci
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= (constraints - 1); j = j + 1) {
            if (colHeaders[j] != null) {
                lastRowNodes[j].down = colHeaders[j];   //  Le dernier noeud simple de la colonne pointe vers l'entête de colonne
                lastColHeader.right = colHeaders[j];    //  La précédente entête de colonne pointe vers celle-ci
                lastColHeader = colHeaders[j];          //  La dernière entête de colonne est celle-ci
            }
        }
        if (lastRowHeader != rootHeader) {
            lastRowHeader.down = rootHeader;            //  La dernière entête de ligne pointe vers l'entête des entêtes
        }
        if (lastColHeader != rootHeader) {
            lastColHeader.right = rootHeader;           //  La dernière entête de colonne pointe vers l'entête des entêtes
        }
        lastColNode = null;
        colHeaders = null;
        lastRowNodes = null;
        sats = null;
    }

    private void mergeCellsIntoSatsMatrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= (gridSize - 1); i = i + 1) {
            if (!cells[i].isEmpty()) {
                int r = cellsRowColValueToSatsRow((i / gridRows), (i % gridRows), 0);   //  0 = 1e ligne (pour le chiffre 1)
                for (int k = 0; k <= (gridRows - 1); k = k + 1) {
                    if (k != (cells[i].value - 1)) {
                        Arrays.fill(sats[r + k], false);   //  Ne garder que les contraintes concernant le chiffre cells[i]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void createSatsMatrix() {
        final int CONSTRAINT_TYPES = 4;    //  (RiCj#, Ri#, Ci#, Bi#)

        int candidates = gridSize * gridRows;                  //  729 candidats (R1C1#1 -> R9C9#9)
        int constraints = CONSTRAINT_TYPES * gridSize;         //  81 contraintes x 4 types de contrainte
        sats = new boolean[candidates][constraints];
        int satsCol = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= (gridRows - 1); i = i + 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= (gridRows - 1); j = j + 1) {
                for (int k = 0; k <= (gridRows - 1); k = k + 1) {
                    sats[cellsRowColValueToSatsRow(i, j, k)][satsCol + 0 * gridSize] = true;  //  RiCj#  valeur unique dans la cellule
                    sats[cellsRowColValueToSatsRow(i, k, j)][satsCol + 1 * gridSize] = true;  //  Ri#  valeur unique dans la ligne
                    sats[cellsRowColValueToSatsRow(k, i, j)][satsCol + 2 * gridSize] = true;  //  Ci#  valeur unique dans la colonne
                    int p = squareRows * (i / squareRows) + (k / squareRows);    //  i = n° de carré dans la grille
                    int q = squareRows * (i % squareRows) + (k % squareRows);    //  k = n° de cellule dans le carré
                    sats[cellsRowColValueToSatsRow(p, q, j)][satsCol + 3 * gridSize] = true;  //  Bi#  valeur unique dans le carré
                }
                satsCol = satsCol + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private int cellsRowColValueToSatsRow(int cellsRow, int cellsCol, int cellValueIndex) {   //  cellValueIndex cad cell.value - 1
        return (gridSize * cellsRow + gridRows * cellsCol + cellValueIndex);
    }
}
```

**Here is the SatsNode class:**

```
package com.example.pgyl.sudoku_a;

public class SatsNode {

    //region Variables
    public SatsNode right;      //  Nnoeud simple ou entête de ligne situé à sa droite
    public SatsNode down;       //  Noeud simple ou entête de colonne situé en-dessous de lui
    public SatsNode rowHeader;  //  Si Noeud simple: Entête de sa ligne
    public SatsNode colHeader;  //  Si Noeud simple: Entête de sa colonne
    public int level;           //  Si Noeud simple: niveau auquel le noeud simple a été retenu comme candidat (pour sa ligne, dans la colonne choisie)
    public int coverId;         //  Si Entête de ligne (ou de colonne): Identifiant utilisé pour la couverture de sa ligne (ou de sa colonne)
    public int satsRow;         //  Si Entête de ligne: Index de ligne dans la matrice-mère (satsMatrix)
    public int rowCount;        //  Si Entête de colonne: Nombre de lignes non couvertes dans la colonne
    //endregion

    public SatsNode() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        right = null;
        down = null;
        rowHeader = null;
        colHeader = null;
        level = 0;
        coverId = 0;
        satsRow = 0;
        rowCount = 0;
    }

}
```

The answer comes after a fraction of a second ... What do you think of it ?

Comment: Please provide the entirety of the classes you wish to have reviewed. Links to external source repositories are discouraged because of link rot.

Comment: For which puzzle does it come after a fraction of a second? Could you add test cases?

Comment: The Algorithm X is fast by design, wether with or without dancing links, so all puzzles are solved after a fraction of a second. No need to wait :)

Comment: I am looking for online puzzle generators that use a flat layout _1..437..348..._ do you know where I can find this?